# Batch Rename - Parent folder + text + Incrementing Number per directory

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-rename

I'm trying to build a batch file which will carry out a rename of all subdirectories in a location in the format of 'parent directory filename' followed by underscore followed by '4 digit incrementing number' (new number count for each directory). So for example ABCDEF_0001, ABCDEF_0002, etc. I currently do this using windows software but would love to have the ability to run it as a batch file.

Many thanks!

EDIT - If possible using an address in the bat file rather than drag and drop.

Answer (score 1):

Please se if this is like expected:

[image]

You have to drag and drop the parent folder to the batch file...

```
@echo off
if exist "%~1" (if not exist "%~1\" exit) else (exit)

set Parent=%~nx1
pushd "%~1"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad') do call :Edit "%%a"
exit

:Edit
set /a Counter+=1
set CounterZ=000%Counter%
set CounterZ=%CounterZ:~-4%
ren "%~1" "%Parent%_%CounterZ%"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: This script could fail if you add a subdirectory and run the script a second time.